# Merge the associative array with multiple keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How to merge the associative array with multiple keys.

I have two arrays below:-

```
Array1 = Array
(
    [294] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Underperforming
                )

        )

    [236] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [6] => High
                )

        )
);
Array2 = Array
(
    [294] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Steady
                )

        )

    [236] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Low
                )

        )
);
```

I want these arrays to be merged in PHP and need output like below,
Expecting Output Array:

```
Array (
    [294] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [6] => Underperforming
                    [5] => Steady

                )

        )

    [236] => Array
        (
            [2017] => Array
                (
                    [6] => High
                    [5] => Low 
                )

        )
);
```

The array keys won't change and the values only be change. Both array has same array structure.

Comment: Have you tried [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

Comment: I tried array_merge_recursive($Array1,$Array2); But not getting the expected output.

Comment: It would be great to post the output of `var_export()` instead of the one of `print_r()`. It can be used to quickly produce a small script to generate and verify a solution.

Comment: Hmm... `array_merge_recursive()` doesn't work in your case. Its documentation explains: *"If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."*

Comment: Yeah... for that need a custom script, which compares elements individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($Array1 as $key=>$val){
     if(is_array($val) && is_array($Array2[$key])){
         if(array_keys($val)[0] == array_keys($Array2[$key])[0]){
            $final_array[$key][array_keys($val)[0]] = $Array1[$key][array_keys($Array1[$key])[0]]+$Array2[$key][array_keys($Array2[$key])[0]];
         }
     }

}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/834913

***A slight better approach:-***

```
$final_array = array();

if(count($Array1) >= count($Array2)){

    foreach($Array1 as $key=>$val){
         if(is_array($val) && is_array($Array2[$key])){
                $final_array[$key][array_keys($val)[0]] = $Array1[$key][array_keys($Array1[$key])[0]]+$Array2[$key][array_keys($Array2[$key])[0]];
         }else{
            $final_array[$key] = $val;
         }
    }
}
if(count($Array1) < count($Array2)){

    foreach($Array2 as $key=>$val){
         if(is_array($val) && is_array($Array1[$key])){
                $final_array[$key][array_keys($val)[0]] = $Array1[$key][array_keys($Array1[$key])[0]]+$Array2[$key][array_keys($Array2[$key])[0]];
         }else{
            $final_array[$key] = $val;
         }
    }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/835143

Comment: You will lose data if the first and the second level mismatch in Array1 and Array2.
Take a look: https://eval.in/835125

Comment: @Neodan now you can check my edited answer second part.I have checked it for all cases:- both array are identical or any-one of the array have some more records.

Answer (score 0):

For the recursive merge php have [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) function, but it does not work in your case (because you have the numeric keys).
So need a custom function like this (which compares all elements individually):

```
function multidimensionalMerge(array $mainArray, array $secondArray)
{
    foreach ($secondArray as $k => $v) {
        if (!empty($mainArray[$k])) {
            if (is_array($mainArray[$k]) && is_array($v))
                $mainArray[$k] = multidimensionalMerge($mainArray[$k], $v);
            else
                $mainArray[$k] = $v;
        } else
            $mainArray[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $mainArray;
}
$array3 = multidimensionalMerge($array1, $array2);
```

Example: https://eval.in/835129

Comment: `array_merge_recursive()` doesn't work in this case. Its documentation explains: "If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended."

Comment: @AlivetoDie, Oh, sorry, you are right. I updated my answer.

Comment: Now your answer is right.so +1